# ls -l and sed are both printing output but i only need the latter to do so

Tags: unix, sed, terminal, ls

I have to check the user permissions that have `rwx`, of all files using `sed`. What i have done: `ls -l | sed '/^-rwx/p'` - which gives me the following output:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 myuser domain users 145 May 16 14:31 1.sh 

-rwxr--r-- 1 myuser domain users 145 May 16 14:31 1.sh

-rwxr--r-- 1 myuser domain users 185 May 16 16:50 2.sh

-rwxr--r-- 1 myuser domain users 185 May 16 16:50 2.sh

-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser domain users  13 May 16 14:31 compiler.c

-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser domain users   2 May 16 14:28 s.txt
```

I'm assuming that both `ls` and `sed` are printing their outputs. With `grep` it works fine and only returns `1.sh` and `2.sh` which is correct, but it's specified to be done with `sed` in the exercise.

Comment: `man sed` and look up what the `p` instruction does. Now look for `-n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the `sed` opts `-n`

```
-n, --quiet, --silent
    suppress automatic printing of pattern space
```

So it would be `ls -l | sed -n '/^-rwx/p'`

Comment: Thank you so much, i saw the option in man but didn't understand it